# Increase stack size with XCode

Tags: xcode, g++

I developed a command line application on Linux which needs its stack to be increased. On Linux I just used the workaround: `ulimit -s unlimited` before running the program. On Mac OS X, command line with G++, I add to the compilation options:

```
-Wl,-stack_size,0x10000000
```

and it works.

Now I am developing this program with XCODE, where should I add this option?

Comment: Is that the largest possible stack size?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the project window:

Targets > [Your target] > info > Build > Other Linker Flags > [your flags]

Comment: thanks

as 

-Wl,-stack_size,0x10000000

or


-stack_size,0x10000000

?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, you can, but under certain conditions. Lets see what does the Swift documenation says about this.

```
var stackSize: Int { get set }
```

> This value must be in bytes and a multiple of 4KB. To change the stack
> size, you must set this property before starting your thread. Setting
> the stack size after the thread has started changes the attribute size
> (which is reflected by the stackSize method), but it does not affect
> the actual number of pages set aside for the thread.