# osx c++ max memory

Tags: c++, macos, memory

I'm writing a c++ program that needs to initialise large arrays of unsigned chars when the program starts.

Once the size of the arrays surpasses around 1.5gb my program crashes with the mmap error code = 12 message. The computer as 4gb of ram so I would like to utilise more of this but obviously not the whole 4gb.

Is there any way to increase the amount of memory my program can use? Is this something set in the compiler in xcode or is this a mac setting that can be changed?

Comment: I think what you want can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2092495/991425

Comment: Also make sure that other things aren't taking up the remaining space.

Comment: @Haatschii: No, the stack size is irrelevant. He's running out of heap memory.

Comment: The obvious question is: are you building a 32-bit or 64-bit binary?

Comment: @mydogisbox: OS X has virtual memory, and automatically expands its swapfiles as needed, so "the remaining space" is nearly infinite (certainly more than 1.5GB), unless he's out of disk space on his primary drive. (gordonfreeman, are you out of disk space?)

Comment: 1.5GB is suspiciously close to the virtual address space limits of a 32-bit process.