# CGAL::Delaunay_d C++ on UCI Seeds dataset: “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”

Tags: c++, macos, exc-bad-access, triangulation, cgal

For my PhD work, I need to construct the Delaunay triangulation (DT) of a given point set in any (low) dimension. So far, I have been using the C++ CGAL library with data up to 4D without any noticeable problem.

However, as I used the same class CGAL::Delaunay_d as I previously used on an 7D data set (namely [UCI repository *Seeds* data set](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00236/seeds_dataset.txt) ), it seems like something is going wrong and I don't know how to trace my problem.

Here is a copy-pastable code to reproduce the execution:

```
// CGAL includes
#include <CGAL/Cartesian_d.h>
#include <CGAL/Delaunay_d.h>
#include <CGAL/Gmpq.h>

// STANDARD includes
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

// TYPEDEFS
typedef CGAL::Gmpq                              EXACT_RT;
typedef CGAL::Cartesian_d<EXACT_RT>             EXACT_Kernel; 
typedef EXACT_Kernel::Point_d                   EXACT_Point;
typedef EXACT_Kernel::Vector_d                  EXACT_Vector;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_d<EXACT_Kernel>          EXACT_Delaunay_any_d;
typedef EXACT_Delaunay_any_d::Vertex_handle     EXACT_Vertex_handle;

// NAMESPACES
using namespace std;
using namespace CGAL;

// FUNCTIONS
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
void delaunay_d(EXACT_Delaunay_any_d &DT, const map <unsigned, vector<EXACT_RT> > &data);
map <unsigned, vector<EXACT_RT> > data_parse(const string &data_set);

// DATASET
char seeds_data_char[] = "15,26 14,84   0,871   5,763   3,312   2,221   5,22\n\
14,88   14,57   0,8811  5,554   3,333   1,018   4,956\n\
14,29   14,09   0,905   5,291   3,337   2,699   4,825\n\
13,84   13,94   0,8955  5,324   3,379   2,259   4,805\n\
16,14   14,99   0,9034  5,658   3,562   1,355   5,175\n\
14,38   14,21   0,8951  5,386   3,312   2,462   4,956\n\
14,69   14,49   0,8799  5,563   3,259   3,586   5,219\n\
14,11   14,1    0,8911  5,42    3,302   2,7 5\n\
16,63   15,46   0,8747  6,053   3,465   2,04    5,877\n\
16,44   15,25   0,888   5,884   3,505   1,969   5,533\n\
15,26   14,85   0,8696  5,714   3,242   4,543   5,314\n\
14,03   14,16   0,8796  5,438   3,201   1,717   5,001\n\
13,89   14,02   0,888   5,439   3,199   3,986   4,738\n\
13,78   14,06   0,8759  5,479   3,156   3,136   4,872\n\
13,74   14,05   0,8744  5,482   3,114   2,932   4,825\n\
14,59   14,28   0,8993  5,351   3,333   4,185   4,781\n\
13,99   13,83   0,9183  5,119   3,383   5,234   4,781\n\
15,69   14,75   0,9058  5,527   3,514   1,599   5,046\n\
14,7    14,21   0,9153  5,205   3,466   1,767   4,649\n\
12,72   13,57   0,8686  5,226   3,049   4,102   4,914\n\
14,16   14,4    0,8584  5,658   3,129   3,072   5,176\n\
14,11   14,26   0,8722  5,52    3,168   2,688   5,219\n\
15,88   14,9    0,8988  5,618   3,507   0,7651  5,091\n\
12,08   13,23   0,8664  5,099   2,936   1,415   4,961\n\
15,01   14,76   0,8657  5,789   3,245   1,791   5,001\n\
16,19   15,16   0,8849  5,833   3,421   0,903   5,307\n\
13,02   13,76   0,8641  5,395   3,026   3,373   4,825\n\
12,74   13,67   0,8564  5,395   2,956   2,504   4,869\n\
14,11   14,18   0,882   5,541   3,221   2,754   5,038\n\
13,45   14,02   0,8604  5,516   3,065   3,531   5,097\n\
13,16   13,82   0,8662  5,454   2,975   0,8551  5,056\n\
15,49   14,94   0,8724  5,757   3,371   3,412   5,228\n\
14,09   14,41   0,8529  5,717   3,186   3,92    5,299\n\
13,94   14,17   0,8728  5,585   3,15    2,124   5,012\n\
15,05   14,68   0,8779  5,712   3,328   2,129   5,36\n\
16,12   15  0,9 5,709   3,485   2,27    5,443\n\
16,2    15,27   0,8734  5,826   3,464   2,823   5,527\n\
17,08   15,38   0,9079  5,832   3,683   2,956   5,484\n\
14,8    14,52   0,8823  5,656   3,288   3,112   5,309\n\
14,28   14,17   0,8944  5,397   3,298   6,685   5,001\n\
13,54   13,85   0,8871  5,348   3,156   2,587   5,178\n\
13,5    13,85   0,8852  5,351   3,158   2,249   5,176\n\
13,16   13,55   0,9009  5,138   3,201   2,461   4,783\n\
15,5    14,86   0,882   5,877   3,396   4,711   5,528\n\
15,11   14,54   0,8986  5,579   3,462   3,128   5,18\n\
13,8    14,04   0,8794  5,376   3,155   1,56    4,961\n\
15,36   14,76   0,8861  5,701   3,393   1,367   5,132\n\
14,99   14,56   0,8883  5,57    3,377   2,958   5,175\n\
14,79   14,52   0,8819  5,545   3,291   2,704   5,111\n\
14,86   14,67   0,8676  5,678   3,258   2,129   5,351\n\
14,43   14,4    0,8751  5,585   3,272   3,975   5,144\n\
15,78   14,91   0,8923  5,674   3,434   5,593   5,136\n\
14,49   14,61   0,8538  5,715   3,113   4,116   5,396\n\
14,33   14,28   0,8831  5,504   3,199   3,328   5,224\n\
14,52   14,6    0,8557  5,741   3,113   1,481   5,487\n\
15,03   14,77   0,8658  5,702   3,212   1,933   5,439\n\
14,46   14,35   0,8818  5,388   3,377   2,802   5,044\n\
14,92   14,43   0,9006  5,384   3,412   1,142   5,088\n\
15,38   14,77   0,8857  5,662   3,419   1,999   5,222\n\
12,11   13,47   0,8392  5,159   3,032   1,502   4,519\n\
11,42   12,86   0,8683  5,008   2,85    2,7 4,607\n\
11,23   12,63   0,884   4,902   2,879   2,269   4,703\n\
12,36   13,19   0,8923  5,076   3,042   3,22    4,605\n\
13,22   13,84   0,868   5,395   3,07    4,157   5,088\n\
12,78   13,57   0,8716  5,262   3,026   1,176   4,782\n\
12,88   13,5    0,8879  5,139   3,119   2,352   4,607\n\
14,34   14,37   0,8726  5,63    3,19    1,313   5,15\n\
14,01   14,29   0,8625  5,609   3,158   2,217   5,132\n\
14,37   14,39   0,8726  5,569   3,153   1,464   5,3\n\
12,73   13,75   0,8458  5,412   2,882   3,533   5,067\n\
17,63   15,98   0,8673  6,191   3,561   4,076   6,06\n\
16,84   15,67   0,8623  5,998   3,484   4,675   5,877\n\
17,26   15,73   0,8763  5,978   3,594   4,539   5,791\n\
19,11   16,26   0,9081  6,154   3,93    2,936   6,079\n\
16,82   15,51   0,8786  6,017   3,486   4,004   5,841\n\
16,77   15,62   0,8638  5,927   3,438   4,92    5,795\n\
17,32   15,91   0,8599  6,064   3,403   3,824   5,922\n\
20,71   17,23   0,8763  6,579   3,814   4,451   6,451\n\
18,94   16,49   0,875   6,445   3,639   5,064   6,362\n\
17,12   15,55   0,8892  5,85    3,566   2,858   5,746\n\
16,53   15,34   0,8823  5,875   3,467   5,532   5,88\n\
18,72   16,19   0,8977  6,006   3,857   5,324   5,879\n\
20,2    16,89   0,8894  6,285   3,864   5,173   6,187\n\
19,57   16,74   0,8779  6,384   3,772   1,472   6,273\n\
19,51   16,71   0,878   6,366   3,801   2,962   6,185\n\
18,27   16,09   0,887   6,173   3,651   2,443   6,197\n\
18,88   16,26   0,8969  6,084   3,764   1,649   6,109\n\
18,98   16,66   0,859   6,549   3,67    3,691   6,498\n\
21,18   17,21   0,8989  6,573   4,033   5,78    6,231\n\
20,88   17,05   0,9031  6,45    4,032   5,016   6,321\n\
20,1    16,99   0,8746  6,581   3,785   1,955   6,449\n\
18,76   16,2    0,8984  6,172   3,796   3,12    6,053\n\
18,81   16,29   0,8906  6,272   3,693   3,237   6,053\n\
18,59   16,05   0,9066  6,037   3,86    6,001   5,877\n\
18,36   16,52   0,8452  6,666   3,485   4,933   6,448\n\
16,87   15,65   0,8648  6,139   3,463   3,696   5,967\n\
19,31   16,59   0,8815  6,341   3,81    3,477   6,238\n\
18,98   16,57   0,8687  6,449   3,552   2,144   6,453\n\
18,17   16,26   0,8637  6,271   3,512   2,853   6,273\n\
18,72   16,34   0,881   6,219   3,684   2,188   6,097\n\
16,41   15,25   0,8866  5,718   3,525   4,217   5,618\n\
17,99   15,86   0,8992  5,89    3,694   2,068   5,837\n\
19,46   16,5    0,8985  6,113   3,892   4,308   6,009\n\
19,18   16,63   0,8717  6,369   3,681   3,357   6,229\n\
18,95   16,42   0,8829  6,248   3,755   3,368   6,148\n\
18,83   16,29   0,8917  6,037   3,786   2,553   5,879\n\
18,85   16,17   0,9056  6,152   3,806   2,843   6,2\n\
17,63   15,86   0,88    6,033   3,573   3,747   5,929\n\
19,94   16,92   0,8752  6,675   3,763   3,252   6,55\n\
18,55   16,22   0,8865  6,153   3,674   1,738   5,894\n\
18,45   16,12   0,8921  6,107   3,769   2,235   5,794\n\
19,38   16,72   0,8716  6,303   3,791   3,678   5,965\n\
19,13   16,31   0,9035  6,183   3,902   2,109   5,924\n\
19,14   16,61   0,8722  6,259   3,737   6,682   6,053\n\
20,97   17,25   0,8859  6,563   3,991   4,677   6,316\n\
19,06   16,45   0,8854  6,416   3,719   2,248   6,163\n\
18,96   16,2    0,9077  6,051   3,897   4,334   5,75\n\
19,15   16,45   0,889   6,245   3,815   3,084   6,185\n\
18,89   16,23   0,9008  6,227   3,769   3,639   5,966\n\
20,03   16,9    0,8811  6,493   3,857   3,063   6,32\n\
20,24   16,91   0,8897  6,315   3,962   5,901   6,188\n\
18,14   16,12   0,8772  6,059   3,563   3,619   6,011\n\
16,17   15,38   0,8588  5,762   3,387   4,286   5,703\n\
18,43   15,97   0,9077  5,98    3,771   2,984   5,905\n\
15,99   14,89   0,9064  5,363   3,582   3,336   5,144\n\
18,75   16,18   0,8999  6,111   3,869   4,188   5,992\n\
18,65   16,41   0,8698  6,285   3,594   4,391   6,102\n\
17,98   15,85   0,8993  5,979   3,687   2,257   5,919\n\
20,16   17,03   0,8735  6,513   3,773   1,91    6,185\n\
17,55   15,66   0,8991  5,791   3,69    5,366   5,661\n\
18,3    15,89   0,9108  5,979   3,755   2,837   5,962\n\
18,94   16,32   0,8942  6,144   3,825   2,908   5,949\n\
15,38   14,9    0,8706  5,884   3,268   4,462   5,795\n\
16,16   15,33   0,8644  5,845   3,395   4,266   5,795\n\
15,56   14,89   0,8823  5,776   3,408   4,972   5,847\n\
15,38   14,66   0,899   5,477   3,465   3,6 5,439\n\
17,36   15,76   0,8785  6,145   3,574   3,526   5,971\n\
15,57   15,15   0,8527  5,92    3,231   2,64    5,879\n\
15,6    15,11   0,858   5,832   3,286   2,725   5,752\n\
16,23   15,18   0,885   5,872   3,472   3,769   5,922\n\
13,07   13,92   0,848   5,472   2,994   5,304   5,395\n\
13,32   13,94   0,8613  5,541   3,073   7,035   5,44\n\
13,34   13,95   0,862   5,389   3,074   5,995   5,307\n\
12,22   13,32   0,8652  5,224   2,967   5,469   5,221\n\
11,82   13,4    0,8274  5,314   2,777   4,471   5,178\n\
11,21   13,13   0,8167  5,279   2,687   6,169   5,275\n\
11,43   13,13   0,8335  5,176   2,719   2,221   5,132\n\
12,49   13,46   0,8658  5,267   2,967   4,421   5,002\n\
12,7    13,71   0,8491  5,386   2,911   3,26    5,316\n\
10,79   12,93   0,8107  5,317   2,648   5,462   5,194\n\
11,83   13,23   0,8496  5,263   2,84    5,195   5,307\n\
12,01   13,52   0,8249  5,405   2,776   6,992   5,27\n\
12,26   13,6    0,8333  5,408   2,833   4,756   5,36\n\
11,18   13,04   0,8266  5,22    2,693   3,332   5,001\n\
11,36   13,05   0,8382  5,175   2,755   4,048   5,263\n\
11,19   13,05   0,8253  5,25    2,675   5,813   5,219\n\
11,34   12,87   0,8596  5,053   2,849   3,347   5,003\n\
12,13   13,73   0,8081  5,394   2,745   4,825   5,22\n\
11,75   13,52   0,8082  5,444   2,678   4,378   5,31\n\
11,49   13,22   0,8263  5,304   2,695   5,388   5,31\n\
12,54   13,67   0,8425  5,451   2,879   3,082   5,491\n\
12,02   13,33   0,8503  5,35    2,81    4,271   5,308\n\
12,05   13,41   0,8416  5,267   2,847   4,988   5,046\n\
12,55   13,57   0,8558  5,333   2,968   4,419   5,176\n\
11,14   12,79   0,8558  5,011   2,794   6,388   5,049\n\
12,1    13,15   0,8793  5,105   2,941   2,201   5,056\n\
12,44   13,59   0,8462  5,319   2,897   4,924   5,27\n\
12,15   13,45   0,8443  5,417   2,837   3,638   5,338\n\
11,35   13,12   0,8291  5,176   2,668   4,337   5,132\n\
11,24   13  0,8359  5,09    2,715   3,521   5,088\n\
11,02   13  0,8189  5,325   2,701   6,735   5,163\n\
11,55   13,1    0,8455  5,167   2,845   6,715   4,956\n\
11,27   12,97   0,8419  5,088   2,763   4,309   5\n\
11,4    13,08   0,8375  5,136   2,763   5,588   5,089\n\
10,83   12,96   0,8099  5,278   2,641   5,182   5,185\n\
10,8    12,57   0,859   4,981   2,821   4,773   5,063\n\
11,26   13,01   0,8355  5,186   2,71    5,335   5,092\n\
10,74   12,73   0,8329  5,145   2,642   4,702   4,963\n\
11,48   13,05   0,8473  5,18    2,758   5,876   5,002\n\
12,21   13,47   0,8453  5,357   2,893   1,661   5,178\n\
11,41   12,95   0,856   5,09    2,775   4,957   4,825\n\
12,46   13,41   0,8706  5,236   3,017   4,987   5,147\n\
12,19   13,36   0,8579  5,24    2,909   4,857   5,158\n\
11,65   13,07   0,8575  5,108   2,85    5,209   5,135\n\
12,89   13,77   0,8541  5,495   3,026   6,185   5,316\n\
11,56   13,31   0,8198  5,363   2,683   4,062   5,182\n\
11,81   13,45   0,8198  5,413   2,716   4,898   5,352\n\
10,91   12,8    0,8372  5,088   2,675   4,179   4,956\n\
11,23   12,82   0,8594  5,089   2,821   7,524   4,957\n\
10,59   12,41   0,8648  4,899   2,787   4,975   4,794\n\
10,93   12,8    0,839   5,046   2,717   5,398   5,045\n\
11,27   12,86   0,8563  5,091   2,804   3,985   5,001\n\
11,87   13,02   0,8795  5,132   2,953   3,597   5,132\n\
10,82   12,83   0,8256  5,18    2,63    4,853   5,089\n\
12,11   13,27   0,8639  5,236   2,975   4,132   5,012\n\
12,8    13,47   0,886   5,16    3,126   4,873   4,914\n\
12,79   13,53   0,8786  5,224   3,054   5,483   4,958\n\
13,37   13,78   0,8849  5,32    3,128   4,67    5,091\n\
12,62   13,67   0,8481  5,41    2,911   3,306   5,231\n\
12,76   13,38   0,8964  5,073   3,155   2,828   4,83\n\
12,38   13,44   0,8609  5,219   2,989   5,472   5,045\n\
12,67   13,32   0,8977  4,984   3,135   2,3 4,745\n\
11,18   12,72   0,868   5,009   2,81    4,051   4,828\n\
12,7    13,41   0,8874  5,183   3,091   8,456   5\n\
12,37   13,47   0,8567  5,204   2,96    3,919   5,001\n\
12,19   13,2    0,8783  5,137   2,981   3,631   4,87\n\
11,23   12,88   0,8511  5,14    2,795   4,325   5,003\n\
13,2    13,66   0,8883  5,236   3,232   8,315   5,056\n\
11,84   13,21   0,8521  5,175   2,836   3,598   5,044\n\
12,3    13,34   0,8684  5,243   2,974   5,637   5,063";

//////////
// MAIN //
//////////
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    // DATA SET declaration
    string seeds_data(seeds_data_char); 
    map <unsigned, vector<EXACT_RT> > my_DATA = data_parse(seeds_data);

    // DT declaration
    EXACT_Delaunay_any_d my_DT(7);

    // DT construction
    delaunay_d(my_DT, my_DATA);

    return 0;
}

// DELAUNAY TRIANGULATION function
void delaunay_d(
                EXACT_Delaunay_any_d &DT, 
                const map <unsigned, vector<EXACT_RT> > &data) 
{

    // Dim size variable
    int d = ((data.begin()) ->second).size();
    int i = 1;

    // Scanning data set -- DT construction
    for(map <unsigned, vector<EXACT_RT> >::const_iterator it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); it++, i++){

        // Constructing Point objects
        EXACT_Point tmp = EXACT_Point(d, (it ->second).begin(), (it ->second).end());

        // Inserting point in the triangulation
        EXACT_Vertex_handle v_tmp = DT.insert(tmp);

        // DEBUG
        std::cout << "-- DEBUG POST -- " << i << " -- DT.all_simplices().size() : " << DT.all_simplices().size() << " -- DT.current_dimension() : " << DT.current_dimension() << endl;
    }
}

// PARSING DATA function
map <unsigned, vector<EXACT_RT> > data_parse(
                                             const string &data_set)
{
    // RETURNED map
    map <unsigned, vector<EXACT_RT> > result;

    // TMP variables declaration
    vector<EXACT_RT> vect;
    string tmp_value;
    char current_char;

    for (unsigned i=0; i<data_set.length(); i++)
    {
        current_char = data_set[i];

        // Testing if read character is tab or space (i.e. end of a number) ...
        if( (current_char == '\t') ||  (current_char == ' ')) {

            double curr_num = atof(tmp_value.c_str());
            vect.push_back(EXACT_RT(curr_num));  // Storing the double value.
            tmp_value.clear();  // Clearing current number
        }
        //  ... end of a line ...
        else
            if ( (current_char == '\n') || (current_char == '\r') ) {

                double curr_num = atof(tmp_value.c_str());
                vect.push_back(EXACT_RT(curr_num));  // Storing the double value.

                result.insert ( pair <unsigned, vector<EXACT_RT> > (i++, vect) );  // Feeding returned map

                tmp_value.clear();  // Clearing current number
                vect.clear();  // Clearing the vector containing the converted values
            }   

        // .. storing any other character
            else {

                // Dealing with decimal character (from ',' to '.')
                if(current_char == ',') {

                    // Storing current character
                    tmp_value.push_back('.');
                }
                else

                    // Storing current character
                    tmp_value.push_back(current_char);
            }
    }

    return result;

}
```

As I used exact number type `CGAL::Gmpq` for the computation of the DT, I suspect an internal bug of CGAL but I can't assert it. My error actually occurs within the call of function `EXACT_Delaunay_any_d::insert()`and I don't know how to find a way to debug it.

An “EXC_BAD_ACCESS” signal stops my program while trying to insert the 78-th point, after construction of 20926 simplices.

My questions are:

- Should I use some other exact number type ?
- Is it an internal issue of CGAL function `EXACT_Delaunay_any_d::insert()` ?
- Is it a problem of memory allocation related to my OS (Mac OS X 10.6.8) ?

Thanks in advance if you have any answer / clue for investigation !

Octavio

Comment: Posting a small reproducible testcase would help. I don't see anything particularly wrong in the extremely little you have shown.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: As requested, I put some elements for reproducing my execution. Do you need the code I use to put the data in the map ?

Comment: Either we (not me in particular) can reproduce it (you give us complete code that we can directly copy-paste, compile, run and see the same issue) and we can start working, or the guesswork is likely to be a waste of time (yours as well as ours). Note that this is a general principle, there are tutorials on the web on how to report bugs in a productive way. It is good to remove irrelevant parts of the program, but what is left should still compile as is and exhibit the problem.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: Ok. According to your notice, please find above copy-pastable code.

Comment: After replacing `,` with `.` and consecutive spaces with a single one in `seeds_data_char` (it would have been simpler to initialize an array instead of parsing a string), it works for me on linux (on line 77 it says the size is 20926, so I assume I did the right fix). What exact command line are you using? It doesn't seem to use much memory, so that shouldn't be the problem. (I didn't remember it was this slow, it will be good when we get the new code...)

Comment: Hmm, actually, it did crash for point 115...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, you just reported a stack overflow on stackoverflow.com.

The function `visibility_search` in Convex_hull_d.h is recursive (not a terminal recursion) and the depth of the recursion is apparently not bounded. This is a bug. You should be able to get a bit further by increasing the stack size (the procedure is explained in other questions on this site). Let us know how that fares.

You can also try to reduce other stack use. Maybe using `mpq_class` or `CGAL::Quotient<CGAL::MP_Float>` instead of `CGAL::Gmpq` would help, or it might be even worse. You could also recompile the GMP library after replacing 65536 with 1024 in gmp-impl.h.

Comment: Thanks Marc for your answer.

As you suggested, I increased the stack size following [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2092517/1608834). Execution DID NOT crash and up to 1.3Go of memory was eventually used, as I monitored the execution. 

What is the reported max dimension and data cardinality for DT construction using CGAL ?

Do you know when this (recursion) bug might be fixed ?

I will consider changing the number types as well and report how the code behaves, as you suggested.

Comment: I have no idea what large triangulations people have been building. A complete rewriting of high dimension triangulations is in the works, but no ETA, sorry. This may also mean that people won't be motivated to fix this bug in the old code, especially since increasing the stack size works around it.