# Memory Allocation Error, possibly in GDB

Tags: c++, xcode, memory-management

I started experiencing a BAD_ACCESS error in Xcode 4.6.3 while testing a fairly large program. I traced the error up to the following point:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    float test1[1024][1536];
    float test2[340][1536];
    std::cout << "Made it up to this point!\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The program as above will run fine. But if I increase the array size beyond [340][1536], it will crash with

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x7fff00000de4)
```

Evidently, the debugger is unable to allocate enough memory for the program to use. Any ideas on how to solve the problem?

Edit: I also found that I get errors on static allocations such as

```
float a[123][456]
```

which worked fine a day earlier. So, this could be a compiler option.

Comment: It seems that you're running out of stack memory for your current program. Try dynamically allocating the arrays, atleast the second array.

Comment: This works, but when it comes to the actual program I was testing, it means I have to change methods written by others (and working properly in other projects). Most likely I have a compiler option that is incorrect.

Comment: You can try increasing the stack size: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092495/increase-stack-size-with-xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since main cannot be called more than once you won't lose anything by making these arrays static

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    static float test1[1024][1536];
    static float test2[340][1536];
    std::cout << "Made it up to this point!\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This worked. The alternative is to declare them dynamically, but this is easier to code and works when you are in the main().