# Can't figure out "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error while working with arrays

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, memory, exc-bad-access

I'm working on an algorithm that sorts inputted integers in ascending order.

The input should be of sort

```
5
32
45
32
55
67
```

and the output of sort

```
32
32
45
55
67
```

where the first integer input is the number of integers that will be inputted.

n.b. the integer inputted n is 1 <= n <= 10,000,000.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int N;
    scanf("%d", &N); // receives the number of integers that will be inputted
    int countArray[10000000] = {0}; // creates an array that will store the number of times a number is inputted. the inputted number is the corresponding address e.g. countArray[number-1] stores the amount of times the number 'number' is inputted.

    int inputArray[N]; // creates an array of the numbers inputted
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &inputArray[i]); // receives the numbers inputted and stores them in the inputArray
    }
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++) {
        countArray[inputArray[i]-1]++; // counts the number of times a number occurs in inputArray and increments the corresponding value in the countArray.
    }
    int i=0;
    while (i<10000000) {
        if (countArray[i] > 0) {
            for (int j=0;j<countArray[i];j++) { // prints out the numbers only if count is greater than 0.
                printf("%d\n", i+1);
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I know my code isn't the most efficient way to sort the inputs; I'm just curious as to why I get a "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error when the size of the array is 10,000,000 but not when it is 1,000,000. It works just fine if the array is of size 1,000,000 but not when it is 10,000,000.

Comment: What kind of system are you running on? How large does the system allow the stack to grow?

Comment: You would need 40 megabytes (assuming 32-bit integers) of stack space for that array.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571945/getting-a-stack-overflow-exception-when-declaring-a-large-array

Comment: Dear OP, I recommend using dynamic allocation to heap with `malloc()` when working with such large chunks of memory, since as @tevemadar rightly pointed out, 40 `MiB` does not sounds more apt for `malloc()` :) My guess is possible *stack overflow* ...

Comment: Does anyone else see a problem with `int inputArray[N]` since `N` is a run-time variable and arrays are static ? I get `8:19: warning: variable length array used [-Wvla]` ....

Comment: I'm running the code on a Mac in Xcode. I'm not sure about how large the stack is allowed to be...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092495/increase-stack-size-with-xcode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample code *does compile* at least, but **does not run**. It seg-faults on start .

With GCC + Linux, and I get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` and it exits with code `139` , while on my Mac with Clang, I get `Segmentation fault: 11` with the same exit code. I suspect your `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` is some version with the ***same*** basic issue underlying it.

As pointed out by [@tevemadar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7916438/tevemadar) , you are asking for ~ 40 `MiB` of data in your stack, which, *very evidently*, you are **not** going to get.

**So, instead of this :**

`int countArray[10000000];`

**do this** :

`int *countArray = malloc(10000000*sizeof(int));`

**OR**

`static int countArray[10000000];`

Which *should* work (**don't forget to check for `NULL` !** ) , since `malloc()` will return a *pointer* to memory it allocated in the *heap*, and global variables are also put in the heap, where the size limits are not as restrictive as the *stack*, and for most practical purposes not important to keep in mind.

---

Now, onto some rambling of mine -

You are essentially going **very much** beyond the allowed stack size. I do not claim to be an expert, but by now this much is surely self-evident to you too.

Your attempt is somewhat of an *abuse* of the stack and perhaps arises from not being told the idea behind the stack's purpose - something most C textbooks and courses are guilty of :(

I am not an expert, and will not ruin the beauty of the concept for you, but to summarise -

The ***stack*** is for storing **smaller, local variables** of functions, like counters, strings to print, return values, etc. It's where everything, generally speaking, will go unless you `malloc()` , `fopen()` or `static` it. Its okay for small, handy variables which would be silly to `malloc()`.

The ***heap*** is a **huge region of memory** , intended for **bulk usage** as in linked lists, long arrays, trees, big structs and what not. It's where you *should* store seriously-sized variables which store large amount of *data*.

---

So, TL;DR , use the **heap for large datatypes**, use the **stack of small variables** that would be silly to `malloc()`.